My Alertify prompt can't typing in input field
Click this to show my prompt
I can't typing on my alertify prompt and can't be focus on input field, 1 month before it still can use, but now is not anymore.
Anyone can help ?
I have try to set the z-index bigger than before, but still can't type on input field

Please provide exemple with code
